# mvc4 DropdownList does not set selected value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, html-select

Hi I have a problem that drives me crazy. I have a dropdown list in one page of my project, which should act like on all the other dropdowns on all the other pages but it doesn't and I'm wondeing why.

Here you will see the code in the cshtml page. It's a normal dropdown:

```
<p>
    Specify a organisation to search in
    @Html.DropDownList("OrganisationList", new SelectList(ViewBag.OrganisationList, "ID", "Name", ViewBag.SelectedOrganisation))
</p>
```

In the controller I have a method to bind the dropdownlist and a method that calls the view:

```
private void BindAllOrganisations()
{
    List<OrganisationModel> OrganisationList = new List<OrganisationModel> { new OrganisationModel { ID = null, Name = "Select" } };

    foreach (var Organisation in DatabaseConnection.DataContextRead.GetTable<Organisation>())
    {
        OrganisationList.Add(new OrganisationModel { ID = Organisation.OrganisationId, Name = Organisation.Name });
    }

    ViewBag.OrganisationList = OrganisationList;
}

/**
 * Loads the ManageUserView with all users from a specific organisation unit
 **/
[AzaraAuthorization(RequiredRoles = new[] { RolesEnum.Admin })]
public ActionResult ManageUsersFromOrgUnit(int Id)
{
    try
    {
        var orgUnit = organisationUnitManagement.GetSingleUnit(Id);
        List<AzaraUser> AzaraUserList = azaraUserManagement.GetAllUserFromOrganisationUnit(orgUnit);
        ViewBag.FromOrgUnits = Id;
        BindAllOrganisations();
        ViewBag.SelectedOrganisation = orgUnit.Organisation.OrganisationId;
        return View("ManageUsers", AzaraUserList);
    }
    catch (BusinessObjectNotRetrievableByIdException exc)
    {
        ExceptionHandling.BusinessObjectNotRetrievableByIdExceptionOccured(exc, "ManageUsersFromOrgUnit(int Id)", "ManageUsersController");
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { Info = "A program error occured. The administrator get informed. Apologize the inconvenience." });
    }
}
```

I can't find the problem. Also if I replace `ViewBag.SelectedOrganisation` on the Page with `1` (I know there is a model with value `1` in the database behind) it selects the value with `null`. Here is the used model for the list:

```
public class OrganisationModel
{
    public int? ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Could there be a bug or what have I missed?

Comment: First I encourage you to use strongly typed views instead of viewbag. Second how are you submitting the value to the controller?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12655479/mvc4-selectlist-not-selected-default-object